# vue-cli, npm и установка

Tags: javascript, vue.js, npm, ecmascript-6, vue-cli

Не так давно работаю с Vue js и тд, в каждый проект по фронт енду мне нужно прописать:

```
npm install
```

и

```
npm install -g @vue/cli
```

То есть, я стянул с Git(а) проект и захотел его запустить, но мне написало мол у вас отсутствует vue cli, установил его (выше команда), а потом попросило установить npm как я понял и я ввёл команду `npm install`.
Потом уже с помощью команды `npm run serve` я запустил проект и он открылся.
1 вопрос: 
Зачем для каждого проекта так делать? Или проекты имеют так сказать шаблон, а перед запуском тебе нужно как бы "внедрить" туда определенные технологии?

Comment: Потому что альтернатива - качать из git папку node_modules, которая даже в самых простых фронтенд-проектах весит в тысячи раз больше исходного кода проекта: не 300 килобайт, а сотню мегабайт. Естественно, нет смысла хранить все эти библиотеки в гите.

Comment: у проекта есть файл package где хранятся зависимости и как выше написали чтобы всё это добро не таскать туда сюда вы качаете только файлы проекта, а npm install подтягивает нужные для проекта зависимости

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте создать любой новый проект. Вот у меня пустой проект, созданный через `vue init webpack` и положенный в гит занимает 50 килобайт. Но после команды `npm i` на диске появляется файл package-lock.json на 550 килобайт и папка node_modules размером в 170 мегабайт.

Нет никакой необходимости хранить все эти файлы в репозитории: все эти скачанные десятки и сотни модулей имеют свои репозитории, скомпилированы и готовы к употреблению.

И если даже в этих 50 килобайт вашего кода при старте не очень много (он весь типовой boilerplate), то по мере написания проекта это может изменено, это как раз *ваш* проект, а остальные библиотеки... ну вот вы часто смотрите в исходники подключаемых библиотек?